# Можно ли участников различных форумов называть пользователями?

Tags: лексика

С одной стороны, участники форумов **пользуются услугами системы**, а также  размещенной **информацией** (например, в виде вопросов и ответов), но это скорее **обмен, а не одностороннее пользование.**

Уместно ли в таком  случае называть участников форума пользователями, что соответствует  явно английскому значению слова.

**User** (англ.)  ― пользователь, потребитель, клиент, абонент.

**ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ**, м. чем или чего. Офиц. Лицо или учреждение, пользующееся чем-л. П. персонального компьютера, земель. Постоянные пользователи информационных программ. Договор с пользователем услуг.

Answer (score 2):

> Можно ли участников различных форумов называть пользователями?

Думаю, можно их назвать *пользователями* сайта, на котором данный форум существует. Но они — *участники* форума, а не его *пользователи*, так как форум, в отличие от сайта, не услуга, а результат пользовательской активности (где под пользователями подразумеваются опять-таки пользователи сайта).

Comment: Сочетаемость действительно  разная: участник форума, пользователь сайта. А вот можно сказать про участника форума следующее: пользователь N считает... Или, к примеру, наш иностранный гость разыскивает user V. Но у них это, скорее всего, нормально, а вот как  в русском языке,  допустимо ли слово "пользователь" применять как приложение к имени? Как-то странно звучит и слух напрягает. А вот почему, что вызывает негативную реакцию? У меня есть на этот счет предположения,  но хотелось бы послушать, что думают другие.

Comment: Думаю, дело в том, что исконно русское  слово *пользователь* — это человек пользующий, врачующий кого-либо (см.словарь Даля). А современный пользователь - калька с английского. В русском были потребители, но превратились в пользователей. Может, слово *потребитель* не прошло в мир компьютеров из-за его несколько отрицательной коннотации?

Comment: Пользователь - нормальное слово, во многих случаях мы действительно пользователи услуг (например, телефонной сети). Но речь идет о тех площадках, где речь идет не о пассивных, а об активных пользователях.

Comment: *Пользователь* — это пользователь интернета, при употреблении без зависимых слов подходит всегда, подкупает своей универсальностью.

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли участников различных форумов называть пользователями?

В английском языке, в отличие от русского, основное значение слова **форум** (forum) не **собрание**, а **место проведения собрания**. Может быть поэтому **Internet forum** там означает не собрание участников с целью обмена сообщениями, а сам сайт, который обеспечивает такую возможность. Поэтому там и называют участников **system user** (пользователь системы) или просто **user**.

В русском языке ситуация немного отличается. Первое значение слова **форум** — собрание, съезд. **Интернет-форум** зачастую понимается не как **платформа для общения** (именно так сказано в Википедии — в переводной статье с английского языка), а как "собрание для обсуждения". Поэтому слово "участник" многим (мне в том числе) кажется более предпочтительным. Но в этой сфере русский язык находится под сильным влиянием английского, и сложно предсказать, какое слово закрепится в итоге.

Comment: Встречается и forum participants, и forum users.

Comment: @М_Г Дайте ссылку, пожалуйста на participants. Просьба предварительно проследить два условия: а) это интернет-форум, а не что-то вроде съезда; б) это форум в англоязычной стране (не в Китае, например). Вот member встречается, да, но имеет смысловой оттенок.

Comment: **Forum participants** may upload personal pictures onto the site and add descriptions to the pictures...... Forums differ from chats and instant messaging in that **forum participants** do not have to be online simultaneously to receive or send messages (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum)

Comment: @М_Г Не хочу дальше спорить, поскольку не знаю английского языка на уровне носителя, но замечу, что Вы привели цитату из раздела обсуждения **альтернативных технологий** (так называемые чаты и мессенджеры). Я попытался в гугле найти такое употребление, но оно встречается намного реже и каждый раз вызывает какие-то подозрения. В общем, здесь нужно мнение носителя языка, живущего в соответствующей среде.